# Getting KeyErrors when training Hugging Face Transformer

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am generally following this tutorial ([https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training#:~:text=%F0%9F%A4%97%20Transformers%20provides%20access%20to,an%20incredibly%20powerful%20training%20technique.](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training#:%7E:text=%F0%9F%A4%97%20Transformers%20provides%20access%20to,an%20incredibly%20powerful%20training%20technique.)) to implement fine-tuning on a pretrained transformer. The main difference is I am using my own custom dataset that is being sourced from a JSON file that has a document's text and the label it should belong to. To be able to do this I needed to create my own class which is based off of the Dataset class from pytorch. This is what that class looks like:

```
class PDFsDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings, labels):
        self.encodings = encodings
        self.labels = labels

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        
        print("\n\n\n\nindex",idx)
        item = {key: torch.tensor(val[idx]) for key, val in self.encodings.items()}
        item['labels'] = torch.tensor(self.labels[idx])
        return item

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)
```

I am getting an error when training the transformer that says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\e417922\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3621, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 2131, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 2140, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 19

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\e417922\Downloads\enwiki-20220601-pages-meta-history1.xml-p1p857\HF_Transformer.py", line 147, in <module>
    transformer.train_transformer()
  File "c:\Users\e417922\Downloads\enwiki-20220601-pages-meta-history1.xml-p1p857\HF_Transformer.py", line 135, in train_transformer
    trainer.train()
  File "C:\Users\e417922\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py", line 1409, in train
    return inner_training_loop(
  File "C:\Users\e417922\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py", line 1625, in _inner_training_loop
    for step, inputs in enumerate(epoch_iterator):
  File "C:\Users\e417922\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 530, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "C:\Users\e417922\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 570, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "C:\Users\e417922\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 49, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "C:\Users\e417922\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 49, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "c:\Users\e417922\Downloads\enwiki-20220601-pages-meta-history1.xml-p1p857\HF_Transformer.py", line 42, in __getitem__
    for key in self.encodings[idx]:
  File "C:\Users\e417922\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 958, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "C:\Users\e417922\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1069, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "C:\Users\e417922\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3623, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 19
```

The KeyError that it fails on changes each time I run it. I'm a beginner with Transformers and HuggingFace so I have no clue what's causing this problem.

Edit:
Sample Input is a JSON File where elements would look like this:
{
"text_clean": [
"article with a few hundred words",
another article with a lot of words",
"yet another article"
],
"most_similar_label":[
"Quantum"
"Artificial intelligence"
"Materials"
]
}

Full Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import json
import pandas as pd
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import TrainingArguments
from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer
import numpy as np
from datasets import load_metric
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import torch

class PDFsDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings, labels):
        self.encodings = encodings
        self.labels = labels

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        
        print("\n\n\n\nindex",idx)
        item = {key: torch.tensor(val[idx]) for key, val in self.encodings.items()}
        item['labels'] = torch.tensor(self.labels[idx])
        return item

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)

class HFTransformer:
    def __init__ (self):
        pass

    def import_from_json(self):
        #Prompts user to select json file
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        self.json_file_path = filedialog.askopenfile().name
        #opens json file and loads data
        with open(self.json_file_path, "r") as json_file:
                try:
                    json_load = json.load(json_file)
                except:
                    raise ValueError("No PDFs to convert to JSON")
        self.pdfs = json_load
        #converts json file data to dataframe for easier manipulation
        self.pdfs = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(self.pdfs)

        for index in range(len(self.pdfs["new_tags"])):
            if self.pdfs["new_tags"][index] == "":
                self.pdfs["new_tags"][index] = self.pdfs["most_similar_label"][index]

        self.pdfs["labels"] = self.pdfs["new_tags"].apply(lambda val: self.change_tag_to_num(val))
        # for label in self.data["labels"]:
     
    def change_tag_to_num(self, value):
        if value == "Quantum":
            return 0
        elif value == "Artificial intelligence":
            return 1
        elif value == "Materials":
            return 2
        elif value == "Energy":
            return 3
        elif value == "Defense":
            return 4
        elif value == "Satellite":
            return 5
        elif value == "Other":
            return 6

    def tokenize_dataset(self):
        tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")

        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(self.pdfs["text_clean"], self.pdfs["labels"],test_size=0.2)

        train_encodings = X_train.apply(lambda string: tokenizer(string, truncation=True, padding=True,max_length=10))
        test_encodings = X_test.apply(lambda string: tokenizer(string, truncation=True, padding=True,max_length=10))
    
        
        self.train_dataset = PDFsDataset(train_encodings, y_train)
    
        data_to_add = {"input_ids": [], "token_type_ids": [], "attention_mask": []}

        for i in self.train_dataset.encodings:
            data_to_add["input_ids"].append(i["input_ids"])
            data_to_add["token_type_ids"].append(i["token_type_ids"])
            data_to_add["attention_mask"].append(i["attention_mask"])

        self.train_dataset.encodings = data_to_add

        self.eval_dataset = PDFsDataset(test_encodings,y_test)
        data_to_add = {"input_ids": [], "token_type_ids": [], "attention_mask": []}

        for i in self.eval_dataset.encodings:
            data_to_add["input_ids"].append(i["input_ids"])
            data_to_add["token_type_ids"].append(i["token_type_ids"])
            data_to_add["attention_mask"].append(i["attention_mask"])
        
        self.eval_dataset.encodings = data_to_add

    def train_transformer(self):
        model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased", num_labels=7)
        training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir="test_trainer")
        self.metric = load_metric("accuracy")
        training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir="test_trainer", evaluation_strategy="epoch")
    

        trainer = Trainer(
            model=model,
            args=training_args,
            train_dataset=self.train_dataset,
            eval_dataset=self.eval_dataset,
            compute_metrics=self.compute_metrics
        )
        trainer.train()
    def compute_metrics(self, eval_pred):
        logits, labels = eval_pred
        predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
        return self.metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)


if __name__  == "__main__":
    transformer = HFTransformer()
    transformer.import_from_json()
    transformer.tokenize_dataset()
    transformer.train_transformer()
```

Comment: Adding the entire implementation along and a toy sample of the data would help the community spot the issue!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've edited it to include your suggestions.

Comment: If you add a tiny portion of data I would check the program out ASAP @Ben O

Comment: Could I email you or send you it another way? The data is very long and is running into character limit issues with stack overflow.

Comment: A toy example with several rows would be OK, BTW mehdi_j94@outlook.com

Comment: Sounds good! Sent you an email

Comment: I've given it the first try, but I didn't manage to fix the issue, I will work on it again at the weekend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting `pandas.Series` into a simple python list and getting rid of some extra materials would fix the issue

```
class PDFsDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings, labels):
        self.encodings = encodings
        self.labels = labels

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item = {key: torch.tensor(val[idx]) for key, val in self.encodings.items()}
        item['labels'] = torch.tensor(self.labels[idx])
        return item

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)

class HFTransformer:
    def __init__ (self):
        pass

    def import_from_json(self):
        #Prompts user to select json file
        self.json_file_path = '/content/truncated_data.json'
        #opens json file and loads data
        with open(self.json_file_path, "r") as json_file:
                try:
                    json_load = json.load(json_file)
                except:
                    raise ValueError("No PDFs to convert to JSON")
        self.pdfs = json_load
        #converts json file data to dataframe for easier manipulation
        self.pdfs = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(self.pdfs)

        for index in range(len(self.pdfs["new_tags"])):
            if self.pdfs["new_tags"][index] == "":
                self.pdfs["new_tags"][index] = self.pdfs["most_similar_label"][index]

        self.pdfs["labels"] = self.pdfs["new_tags"].apply(lambda val: self.change_tag_to_num(val))
        # for label in self.data["labels"]:
     
    def change_tag_to_num(self, value):
        if value == "Quantum":
            return 0
        elif value == "Artificial intelligence":
            return 1
        elif value == "Materials":
            return 2
        elif value == "Energy":
            return 3
        elif value == "Defense":
            return 4
        elif value == "Satellite":
            return 5
        elif value == "Other":
            return 6

    def tokenize_dataset(self):
        tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")

        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(self.pdfs["text_clean"].to_list(), self.pdfs["labels"].to_list(),test_size=0.2)
        train_encodings = tokenizer(X_train, truncation=True, padding=True,max_length=100)
        test_encodings = tokenizer(X_test, truncation=True, padding=True,max_length=100)
        self.train_dataset = PDFsDataset(train_encodings, y_train)
    
        self.eval_dataset = PDFsDataset(test_encodings,y_test)
    
    def train_transformer(self):
        model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased", num_labels=7)
        training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir="test_trainer")
        self.metric = load_metric("accuracy")
        training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir="test_trainer", evaluation_strategy="epoch", )
    
        trainer = Trainer(
            model=model,
            args=training_args,
            train_dataset=self.train_dataset,
            eval_dataset=self.eval_dataset,
            compute_metrics=self.compute_metrics
        )
        trainer.train()
    def compute_metrics(self, eval_pred):
        logits, labels = eval_pred
        predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
        return self.metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)


if __name__  == "__main__":
    tr = HFTransformer()
    tr.import_from_json()
    tr.tokenize_dataset()
    tr.train_transformer()
```